# Thy conditional expectation hath forsaken me

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the excerpt from below from Tao's book on random matrices (pp.64). I can't understand why the three red underlined expressions are equal. Could you please please please help me ?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be applying to the fact conditional on the history I.e you know the quantity at the previous time step.so you can remove the quantity $S_{n-1}$ from the conditional expectation and since you can use tower law on the remainder I believe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality between the first and the second follows from a property of conditional expectation: $E(E(X | Y)) = E(X)$. This is a manifestation of an even more general fact, namely that if $A$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $B$, then

$$E(E(X|A)|B) = E(E(X|B)|A) = E(X|A).$$

It manifests by considering $A = \{ \emptyset, \Omega \}$.

The equality between the second and the third follows from another property of conditional expectation, namely that if $Y$ is $A$-measurable then $E(XY|A)=YE(X|A)$.